# Using Ramda in TypeScript without bundling inside my app code

Tags: typescript, browserify, ramda.js

I am writing a small web app in TypeScript and bundling the final JS with Browserify. The whole JS bundle takes 30 kb without minification.

Now I want to use a few functions of the Ramda library. If I install Ramda via npm and import it from my app code, the resulting bundle grows to more than 300 kb.

So I am loading Ramda as an independent script from `index.html`:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script> <!-- My small app -->
```

Now from my app code I just do:

```
declare var R;
```

And my app has access to all Ramda functions from the R global variable. However, using this approach has a major limitation: R is of type `any`, and there is no type checking available.

So I would want to do `npm install @types/ramda` in order to have all the type checking, but without having to do `npm install ramda` in order to avoid bundling Ramda code in my app.

I have tried many combinations of `import` such as `import R from '@types/ramda'`, but I always get error messages at some stage.

Now I could always just copy the type definitions of Ramda inside my project code... but is there a cleaner way of doing what I want? **In short, is it possible to use Ramda with type checking without bundling all its code in my app? If so, how?**

Comment: Have you tried typing your global variable `R` like this `declare var R: R.Static;`?

Comment: Yes, and I get `[ts] Cannot find namespace 'R'`. I have tried many combinations such as: `import {} from '@types/ramda'; declare var R: R.static;`
Still no way to make typescript understand what I want.

Comment: I've not worked with ramda yet, but we are usually using a [Trippe-Slash Directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) to reference the correct definition file in the typescript file. Like this: `/// <reference types="ramda" />`. And then definining the variable `declare var R: R.Static;`.

Comment: I tried that too, I get the same error: `[ts] Cannot find namespace 'R'`

Comment: Side note: It's been a best practice for a couple years now to NOT go protocol-less for script srcs, but instead to always request HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Browserify is a very simple tool, which is nice for small projects, but for more complex requirements, WebPack is better... so I switched my build scripts to use WebPack.

WebPack has a specific feature precisely to deal with this kind of problem, with the `externals` configuration option. So I just had to add this in `webpack.config.js`:

```
externals: {
    ramda: 'R'
```

}

WebPack is quite complex to setup and configure, so I have created a WebPack template project and documented its configuration. In case you are interested, it is [here](https://github.com/lcrespom/webpack2-ts-template).

Answer (score 0):

You can pull in Ramda using TypeScript import statements like:

```
// Entire library, and equivalent to `conts R = require('ramda');
import * as R from 'ramda';
// Usage
R.pipe(...);

// Specific methods only
import { pipe, filter, keys } from 'ramda';
// Usage
pipe(...);
```

As long as you have `ramda` and `@types/ramda` in your npm dependencies this will work.  Typically `@types/ramda` should be in your npm dev dependencies since after your source is transpiled they aren't used anymore. Also, you don't import `@types/moduleName` into your project the typings are automatically accessed from `node_modules/@types` if the module does not already provide typings.